# How to check in paypal mobile sdk that payment is done through credit card or paypal?

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal mobile sdk version 2.5.0.

I am getting following response

```
environment = sandbox;
"paypal_sdk_version" = "2.5.0";
 platform = iOS;
 "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
 "create_time" = "2014-10-16T05:44:31Z";
 id = @"PAY-dsfdsfdsdsfdssdfdsfdsfdsf"
 intent = sale;
 state = approved;*
```

but I am not getting any such information that I can identify whether payment has been done through credit card or pay pal. How can I come to know about that?

Please help any one.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this PayPal Mobile SDK documentation page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/explore-payment-capabilities/), it looks like that when a payment is *created*, you'll have a lot more information coming back from the server to work with.

Including this bit in the server JSON response:

```
{
    "id": "PAY-0Y160923TT962563MKPXGBRY",
    "create_time": "2014-08-15T19:34:31Z",
    "update_time": "2014-08-15T19:34:32Z",
    "state": "created",
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal",
        "payer_info": {
            "tax_id_type": "BR_CPF",
            "tax_id": "Fh618775690"
        }
    },
```

Comment: I am using paypal mobile sdk which is not giving this response, these response is I think when we use their rest api, but just for knowing this will I have to change my whole code, as other all things are wrokgin using mobile sdk, samething happens in android mobile sdk. We tested with live credit card